# A new question re: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 1

Tags: xml

I'm analyzing a set of tax forms from IRS in XML format. I have tried a number of things suggested by all previous posts and keep getting this errors: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 1.

**And this is a XML file example ( I cut the latter part of the file because it was too long):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile" returnVersion="2022v5.0">
  <ReturnHeader binaryAttachmentCnt="0">
    <ReturnTs>2023-05-26T01:56:55-04:00</ReturnTs>
    <TaxPeriodEndDt>2022-12-31</TaxPeriodEndDt>
    <ReturnTypeCd>990PF</ReturnTypeCd>
    <TaxPeriodBeginDt>2022-01-01</TaxPeriodBeginDt>
    <Filer>
      <EIN>842400930</EIN>
      <BusinessName>
        <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Meredith Haga Foundation Inc</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
      </BusinessName>
      <InCareOfNm>% Bruce Blessing</InCareOfNm>
      <BusinessNameControlTxt>MERE</BusinessNameControlTxt>
      <ForeignPhoneNum>4233402090</ForeignPhoneNum>
      <USAddress>
        <AddressLine1Txt>2970 Highway 11W</AddressLine1Txt>
        <CityNm>Blountville</CityNm>
        <StateAbbreviationCd>TN</StateAbbreviationCd>
        <ZIPCd>37617</ZIPCd>
      </USAddress>
    </Filer>
    <BusinessOfficerGrp>
      <PersonNm>Bruce Blessing</PersonNm>
      <PersonTitleTxt>President</PersonTitleTxt>
      <SignatureDt>2023-05-26</SignatureDt>
    </BusinessOfficerGrp>
    <TaxYr>2022</TaxYr>
    <BuildTS>2023-04-26 12:10:37Z</BuildTS>
  </ReturnHeader>
  <ReturnData documentCnt="3">
    <IRS990PF documentId="IRS990PF" softwareId="22016104" softwareVersionNum="V1.0" documentName="IRS990PF" referenceDocumentName="ReasonableCauseExplanation GeneralExplanationAttachment BinaryAttachment">
      <Organization501c3ExemptPFInd>X</Organization501c3ExemptPFInd>
      <FMVAssetsEOYAmt>24235</FMVAssetsEOYAmt>
      <MethodOfAccountingAccrualInd>X</MethodOfAccountingAccrualInd>
      <AnalysisOfRevenueAndExpenses>
        <ContriRcvdRevAndExpnssAmt>22213</ContriRcvdRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <ScheduleBNotRequiredInd>X</ScheduleBNotRequiredInd>
        <InterestOnSavRevAndExpnssAmt>0</InterestOnSavRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <InterestOnSavNetInvstIncmAmt>0</InterestOnSavNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <InterestOnSavingsAdjNetIncmAmt>0</InterestOnSavingsAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <DividendsRevAndExpnssAmt>0</DividendsRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <DividendsNetInvstIncmAmt>0</DividendsNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <DividendsAdjNetIncmAmt>0</DividendsAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <GrossRentsRevAndExpnssAmt>0</GrossRentsRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <GrossRentsNetInvstIncmAmt>0</GrossRentsNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <GrossRentsAdjNetIncmAmt>0</GrossRentsAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <NetRentalIncomeOrLossAmt>0</NetRentalIncomeOrLossAmt>
        <NetGainSaleAstRevAndExpnssAmt referenceDocumentName="GainLossFromSaleOtherAssetsSchedule">0</NetGainSaleAstRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <GrossSalesPriceAmt>0</GrossSalesPriceAmt>
        <CapGainNetIncmNetInvstIncmAmt>0</CapGainNetIncmNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <IncmModificationsAdjNetIncmAmt>0</IncmModificationsAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <GrossSalesLessRetAndAllwncAmt>0</GrossSalesLessRetAndAllwncAmt>
        <CostOfGoodsSoldAmt>0</CostOfGoodsSoldAmt>
        <GrossProfitRevAndExpnssAmt referenceDocumentName="SalesOfInventorySchedule">0</GrossProfitRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <GrossProfitAdjNetIncmAmt>0</GrossProfitAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <OtherIncomeRevAndExpnssAmt referenceDocumentName="OtherIncomeSchedule2">0</OtherIncomeRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <OtherIncomeNetInvstIncmAmt>0</OtherIncomeNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <OtherIncomeAdjNetIncmAmt>0</OtherIncomeAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <TotalRevAndExpnssAmt>22213</TotalRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <TotalNetInvstIncmAmt>0</TotalNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <TotalAdjNetIncmAmt>0</TotalAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <CompOfcrDirTrstRevAndExpnssAmt>0</CompOfcrDirTrstRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <CompOfcrDirTrstNetInvstIncmAmt>0</CompOfcrDirTrstNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <CompOfcrDirTrstAdjNetIncmAmt>0</CompOfcrDirTrstAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <CompOfcrDirTrstDsbrsChrtblAmt>0</CompOfcrDirTrstDsbrsChrtblAmt>
        <OthEmplSlrsWgsRevAndExpnssAmt>0</OthEmplSlrsWgsRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <OthEmplSlrsWgsNetInvstIncmAmt>0</OthEmplSlrsWgsNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <OthEmplSlrsWgsAdjNetIncmAmt>0</OthEmplSlrsWgsAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <OthEmplSlrsWgsDsbrsChrtblAmt>0</OthEmplSlrsWgsDsbrsChrtblAmt>
        <PensionEmplBnftRevAndExpnssAmt>0</PensionEmplBnftRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <PensionEmplBnftNetInvstIncmAmt>0</PensionEmplBnftNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <PensionEmplBnftAdjNetIncmAmt>0</PensionEmplBnftAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <PensionEmplBnftDsbrsChrtblAmt>0</PensionEmplBnftDsbrsChrtblAmt>
        <LegalFeesRevAndExpnssAmt referenceDocumentName="LegalFeesSchedule">0</LegalFeesRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <LegalFeesNetInvstIncmAmt>0</LegalFeesNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <LegalFeesAdjNetIncmAmt>0</LegalFeesAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <LegalFeesDsbrsChrtblAmt>0</LegalFeesDsbrsChrtblAmt>
        <AccountingFeesRevAndExpnssAmt referenceDocumentName="AccountingFeesSchedule">0</AccountingFeesRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <AccountingFeesNetInvstIncmAmt>0</AccountingFeesNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <AccountingFeesAdjNetIncmAmt>0</AccountingFeesAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <AccountingFeesChrtblPrpsAmt>0</AccountingFeesChrtblPrpsAmt>
        <OtherProfFeesRevAndExpnssAmt referenceDocumentName="OtherProfessionalFeesSchedule">0</OtherProfFeesRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <OtherProfFeesNetInvstIncmAmt>0</OtherProfFeesNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <OtherProfFeesAdjNetIncmAmt>0</OtherProfFeesAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <OtherProfFeesDsbrsChrtblAmt>0</OtherProfFeesDsbrsChrtblAmt>
        <InterestRevAndExpnssAmt>0</InterestRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <InterestNetInvstIncmAmt>0</InterestNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <InterestAdjNetIncmAmt>0</InterestAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <InterestDsbrsChrtblAmt>0</InterestDsbrsChrtblAmt>
        <TaxesRevAndExpnssAmt referenceDocumentName="TaxesSchedule">0</TaxesRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <TaxesNetInvstIncmAmt>0</TaxesNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <TaxesAdjNetIncmAmt>0</TaxesAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <TaxesDsbrsChrtblAmt>0</TaxesDsbrsChrtblAmt>
        <DeprecAndDpltnRevAndExpnssAmt referenceDocumentName="DepreciationSchedule">0</DeprecAndDpltnRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <DeprecAndDpltnNetInvstIncmAmt>0</DeprecAndDpltnNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <DeprecAndDpltnAdjNetIncmAmt>0</DeprecAndDpltnAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <OccupancyRevAndExpnssAmt>0</OccupancyRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <OccupancyNetInvstIncmAmt>0</OccupancyNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <OccupancyAdjNetIncmAmt>0</OccupancyAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <OccupancyDsbrsChrtblAmt>0</OccupancyDsbrsChrtblAmt>
        <TravConfMeetingRevAndExpnssAmt>0</TravConfMeetingRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <TravConfMeetingNetInvstIncmAmt>0</TravConfMeetingNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <TravConfMeetingAdjNetIncmAmt>0</TravConfMeetingAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <TravConfMeetingDsbrsChrtblAmt>0</TravConfMeetingDsbrsChrtblAmt>
        <PrintingAndPubRevAndExpnssAmt>4439</PrintingAndPubRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <PrintingAndPubNetInvstIncmAmt>0</PrintingAndPubNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <PrintingAndPubAdjNetIncmAmt>0</PrintingAndPubAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <PrintingAndPubDsbrsChrtblAmt>0</PrintingAndPubDsbrsChrtblAmt>
        <OtherExpensesRevAndExpnssAmt referenceDocumentName="AmortizationSchedule OtherExpensesSchedule">0</OtherExpensesRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <OtherExpensesNetInvstIncmAmt>0</OtherExpensesNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <OtherExpensesAdjNetIncmAmt>0</OtherExpensesAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <OtherExpensesDsbrsChrtblAmt>0</OtherExpensesDsbrsChrtblAmt>
        <TotOprExpensesRevAndExpnssAmt>4439</TotOprExpensesRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <TotOprExpensesNetInvstIncmAmt>0</TotOprExpensesNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <TotOprExpensesAdjNetIncmAmt>0</TotOprExpensesAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <TotOprExpensesDsbrsChrtblAmt>0</TotOprExpensesDsbrsChrtblAmt>
        <ContriPaidRevAndExpnssAmt>0</ContriPaidRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <ContriPaidDsbrsChrtblAmt>0</ContriPaidDsbrsChrtblAmt>
        <TotalExpensesRevAndExpnssAmt>4439</TotalExpensesRevAndExpnssAmt>
        <TotalExpensesNetInvstIncmAmt>0</TotalExpensesNetInvstIncmAmt>
        <TotalExpensesAdjNetIncmAmt>0</TotalExpensesAdjNetIncmAmt>
        <TotalExpensesDsbrsChrtblAmt>0</TotalExpensesDsbrsChrtblAmt>
        <ExcessRevenueOverExpensesAmt>17774</ExcessRevenueOverExpensesAmt>
        <NetInvestmentIncomeAmt>0</NetInvestmentIncomeAmt>
        <AdjustedNetIncomeAmt>0</AdjustedNetIncomeAmt>
      </AnalysisOfRevenueAndExpenses>
      <Form990PFBalanceSheetsGrp>
        <CashBOYAmt>6461</CashBOYAmt>
        <CashEOYAmt>24235</CashEOYAmt>
        <CashEOYFMVAmt>24235</CashEOYFMVAmt>
        <RcvblFromOfficersBOYAmt>0</RcvblFromOfficersBOYAmt>
        <RcvblFromOfficersEOYAmt referenceDocumentName="OtherReceivablesFromOfficersSchedule">0</RcvblFromOfficersEOYAmt>
        <OtherNtsAndLoansRcvblBOYAmt>0</OtherNtsAndLoansRcvblBOYAmt>
        <OtherNtsAndLoansRcvblEOYAmt referenceDocumentName="OtherNotesLoansReceivableLongSchedule OtherNotesLoansReceivableShortSchedule2">0</OtherNtsAndLoansRcvblEOYAmt>
        <USGovernmentObligationsEOYAmt referenceDocumentName="InvestmentsGovtObligationsSchedule">0</USGovernmentObligationsEOYAmt>
        <CorporateStockEOYAmt referenceDocumentName="InvestmentsCorpStockSchedule">0</CorporateStockEOYAmt>
        <CorporateBondsEOYAmt referenceDocumentName="InvestmentsCorpBondsSchedule">0</CorporateBondsEOYAmt>
        <LandBldgInvestmentsEOYAmt referenceDocumentName="InvestmentsLandSchedule2">0</LandBldgInvestmentsEOYAmt>
        <OtherInvestmentsEOYAmt referenceDocumentName="InvestmentsOtherSchedule2">0</OtherInvestmentsEOYAmt>
        <LandEOYAmt referenceDocumentName="LandEtcSchedule2">0</LandEOYAmt>
        <OtherAssetsBOYAmt referenceDocumentName="OtherAssetsSchedule">0</OtherAssetsBOYAmt>
        <OtherAssetsEOYAmt referenceDocumentName="OtherAssetsSchedule">0</OtherAssetsEOYAmt>
        <OtherAssetsEOYFMVAmt referenceDocumentName="OtherAssetsSchedule">0</OtherAssetsEOYFMVAmt>
        <TotalAssetsBOYAmt>6461</TotalAssetsBOYAmt>
        <TotalAssetsEOYAmt>24235</TotalAssetsEOYAmt>
        <TotalAssetsEOYFMVAmt>24235</TotalAssetsEOYFMVAmt>
        <AccountsPayableBOYAmt>0</AccountsPayableBOYAmt>
        <AccountsPayableEOYAmt>13938</AccountsPayableEOYAmt>
        <GrantsPayableBOYAmt>0</GrantsPayableBOYAmt>
        <GrantsPayableEOYAmt>0</GrantsPayableEOYAmt>
        <DeferredRevenueBOYAmt>0</DeferredRevenueBOYAmt>
        <DeferredRevenueEOYAmt>0</DeferredRevenueEOYAmt>
        <LoansFromOfficersBOYAmt>0</LoansFromOfficersBOYAmt>
        <LoansFromOfficersEOYAmt referenceDocumentName="LoansFromOfficersSchedule">0</LoansFromOfficersEOYAmt>
        <MortgagesAndNotesPayableEOYAmt referenceDocumentName="MortgagesAndNotesPayableSchedule">0</MortgagesAndNotesPayableEOYAmt>
        <OtherLiabilitiesBOYAmt referenceDocumentId="OtherLiabilitiesSch1" referenceDocumentName="OtherLiabilitiesSchedule">0</OtherLiabilitiesBOYAmt>
        <OtherLiabilitiesEOYAmt referenceDocumentId="OtherLiabilitiesSch1" referenceDocumentName="OtherLiabilitiesSchedule">0</OtherLiabilitiesEOYAmt>
        <TotalLiabilitiesBOYAmt>0</TotalLiabilitiesBOYAmt>
        <TotalLiabilitiesEOYAmt>13938</TotalLiabilitiesEOYAmt>
        <OrganizationFollowsFASB117Ind>X</OrganizationFollowsFASB117Ind>
        <NoDonorRstrNetAssestsBOYAmt>6461</NoDonorRstrNetAssestsBOYAmt>
        <NoDonorRstrNetAssestsEOYAmt>10297</NoDonorRstrNetAssestsEOYAmt>
        <TotNetAstOrFundBalancesBOYAmt>6461</TotNetAstOrFundBalancesBOYAmt>
        <TotNetAstOrFundBalancesEOYAmt>10297</TotNetAstOrFundBalancesEOYAmt>
        <TotalLiabilitiesNetAstBOYAmt>6461</TotalLiabilitiesNetAstBOYAmt>
        <TotalLiabilitiesNetAstEOYAmt>24235</TotalLiabilitiesNetAstEOYAmt>
      </Form990PFBalanceSheetsGrp>
      <ChgInNetAssetsFundBalancesGrp>
        <TotNetAstOrFundBalancesBOYAmt>6461</TotNetAstOrFundBalancesBOYAmt>
        <ExcessRevenueOverExpensesAmt>17774</ExcessRevenueOverExpensesAmt>
        <OtherIncreasesAmt referenceDocumentName="OtherIncreasesSchedule">0</OtherIncreasesAmt>
        <SubtotalAmt>24235</SubtotalAmt>
        <OtherDecreasesAmt referenceDocumentId="OtherDecreasesSch1" referenceDocumentName="OtherDecreasesSchedule">13938</OtherDecreasesAmt>
        <TotNetAstOrFundBalancesEOYAmt>10297</TotNetAstOrFundBalancesEOYAmt>
      </ChgInNetAssetsFundBalancesGrp>
      <CapGainsLossTxInvstIncmDetail />
      <ExciseTaxBasedOnInvstIncmGrp>
        <InvestmentIncomeExciseTaxAmt>0</InvestmentIncomeExciseTaxAmt>
        <EstimatedPlusOvpmtIncmTxAmt>309</EstimatedPlusOvpmtIncmTxAmt>
        <ExtsnRequestIncomeTaxPaidAmt>0</ExtsnRequestIncomeTaxPaidAmt>
        <BackupWithholdingWithheldAmt>0</BackupWithholdingWithheldAmt>
        <TotalPaymentsAndCreditsAmt>309</TotalPaymentsAndCreditsAmt>
        <OriginalReturnTaxPaidAmt>0</OriginalReturnTaxPaidAmt>
        <OverpaymentAmt>309</OverpaymentAmt>
        <AppliedToESTaxAmt>0</AppliedToESTaxAmt>
      </ExciseTaxBasedOnInvstIncmGrp>
      <StatementsRegardingActyGrp>
        <LegislativePoliticalActyInd referenceDocumentName="ExplanationOfLegisPoliticalActivities BinaryAttachment">false</LegislativePoliticalActyInd>
        <MoreThan100SpentInd>false</MoreThan100SpentInd>
        <Form1120POLFiledInd>false</Form1120POLFiledInd>
        <Section4955OrganizationTaxAmt>0</Section4955OrganizationTaxAmt>
        <Section4955ManagersTaxAmt>0</Section4955ManagersTaxAmt>
        <TaxReimbursedAmt>0</TaxReimbursedAmt>
        <ActivitiesNotPreviouslyRptInd referenceDocumentName="ActivitiesNotPreviouslyReportedExplanation">false</ActivitiesNotPreviouslyRptInd>
        <ChangesToArticlesOrBylawsInd referenceDocumentName="BinaryAttachment">false</ChangesToArticlesOrBylawsInd>
        <UnrelatedBusIncmOverLimitInd>false</UnrelatedBusIncmOverLimitInd>
        <OrganizationDissolvedEtcInd referenceDocumentName="DissolutionStatement LiquidationExplanationStatement BinaryAttachment">false</OrganizationDissolvedEtcInd>
        <Section508eRqrSatisfiedInd>false</Section508eRqrSatisfiedInd>
        <AtLeast5000InAssetsInd>true</AtLeast5000InAssetsInd>
        <OrgReportOrRegisterStateCd>TN</OrgReportOrRegisterStateCd>
        <Form990PFFiledWithAttyGenInd referenceDocumentId="ExplOfNonFilingWithAGStmt1" referenceDocumentName="ExplanationOfNonFilingWithAGStatement">false</Form990PFFiledWithAttyGenInd>
        <PrivateOperatingFoundationInd>false</PrivateOperatingFoundationInd>
        <NewSubstantialContributorsInd referenceDocumentName="SubstantialContributorsSchedule">false</NewSubstantialContributorsInd>
        <OwnControlledEntityInd referenceDocumentName="TransfersFromControlledEntitiesSchedule TransfersToControlledEntitiesSchedule">false</OwnControlledEntityInd>
        <DonorAdvisedFundInd referenceDocumentName="DonorAdvisedFundStatement">false</DonorAdvisedFundInd>
        <ComplyWithPublicInspRqrInd>false</ComplyWithPublicInspRqrInd>
        <IndividualWithBooksNm>Bruce Blessing</IndividualWithBooksNm>
        <PhoneNum>4233402090</PhoneNum>
        <LocationOfBooksUSAddress>
          <AddressLine1Txt>2970 Highway 11W</AddressLine1Txt>
          <CityNm>Blountville</CityNm>
          <StateAbbreviationCd>TN</StateAbbreviationCd>
          <ZIPCd>37617</ZIPCd>
        </LocationOfBooksUSAddress>
        <ForeignAccountsQuestionInd>false</ForeignAccountsQuestionInd>
      </StatementsRegardingActyGrp>
      <StatementsRegardingActy4720Grp>
        <SaleOrExchDisqualifiedPrsnInd>false</SaleOrExchDisqualifiedPrsnInd>
        <BrrwOrLendDisqualifiedPrsnInd>false</BrrwOrLendDisqualifiedPrsnInd>
        <FurnGoodsDisqualifiedPrsnInd>false</FurnGoodsDisqualifiedPrsnInd>
        <PayCompDisqualifiedPrsnInd>false</PayCompDisqualifiedPrsnInd>
        <TransferAstDisqualifiedPrsnInd>false</TransferAstDisqualifiedPrsnInd>
        <PaymentToGovernmentOfficialInd>false</PaymentToGovernmentOfficialInd>
        <UncorrectedPriorActsInd>false</UncorrectedPriorActsInd>
        <UndistributedIncomePYInd>false</UndistributedIncomePYInd>
        <UndistrIncmSect4942a2NotAppInd referenceDocumentName="Section4942a2ExplanationStatement">false</UndistrIncmSect4942a2NotAppInd>
        <BusinessHoldingsInd>false</BusinessHoldingsInd>
        <JeopardyInvestmentsInd>false</JeopardyInvestmentsInd>
        <UncorrectedPYJeopardyInvstInd>false</UncorrectedPYJeopardyInvstInd>
        <InfluenceLegislationInd>false</InfluenceLegislationInd>
        <InfluenceElectionInd>false</InfluenceElectionInd>
        <GrantsToIndividualsInd>false</GrantsToIndividualsInd>
        <GrantsToOrganizationsInd>false</GrantsToOrganizationsInd>
        <NoncharitablePurposeInd>false</NoncharitablePurposeInd>
        <MaintainedExpenditureRspnsInd referenceDocumentName="ExpenditureResponsibilityStatement">false</MaintainedExpenditureRspnsInd>
        <RcvFndsToPayPrsnlBnftCntrctInd>false</RcvFndsToPayPrsnlBnftCntrctInd>
        <PayPremiumsPrsnlBnftCntrctInd>false</PayPremiumsPrsnlBnftCntrctInd>
        <ProhibitedTaxShelterTransInd>false</ProhibitedTaxShelterTransInd>
        <SubjToTaxRmnrtnExPrchtPymtInd>false</SubjToTaxRmnrtnExPrchtPymtInd>
      </StatementsRegardingActy4720Grp>
      <OfficerDirTrstKeyEmplInfoGrp>
        <OfficerDirTrstKeyEmplGrp>
          <PersonNm referenceDocumentId="CompensationExplanation1" referenceDocumentName="CompensationExplanation">Bruce Blessing</PersonNm>
          <USAddress>
            <AddressLine1Txt>2970 Highway 11W</AddressLine1Txt>
            <CityNm>Blountville</CityNm>
            <StateAbbreviationCd>TN</StateAbbreviationCd>
            <ZIPCd>37617</ZIPCd>
          </USAddress>
          <TitleTxt>President</TitleTxt>
          <AverageHrsPerWkDevotedToPosRt>20.00</AverageHrsPerWkDevotedToPosRt>
          <CompensationAmt>0</CompensationAmt>
          <EmployeeBenefitProgramAmt>0</EmployeeBenefitProgramAmt>
          <ExpenseAccountOtherAllwncAmt>0</ExpenseAccountOtherAllwncAmt>
        </OfficerDirTrstKeyEmplGrp>
        <OfficerDirTrstKeyEmplGrp>
          <PersonNm referenceDocumentId="CompensationExplanation1" referenceDocumentName="CompensationExplanation">Elizabeth McElroy</PersonNm>
          <USAddress>
            <AddressLine1Txt>1309 Camden Dr</AddressLine1Txt>
            <CityNm>Richmond</CityNm>
            <StateAbbreviationCd>VA</StateAbbreviationCd>
            <ZIPCd>23229</ZIPCd>
          </USAddress>
          <TitleTxt>Vice President</TitleTxt>
          <AverageHrsPerWkDevotedToPosRt>5.00</AverageHrsPerWkDevotedToPosRt>
          <CompensationAmt>0</CompensationAmt>
          <EmployeeBenefitProgramAmt>0</EmployeeBenefitProgramAmt>
          <ExpenseAccountOtherAllwncAmt>0</ExpenseAccountOtherAllwncAmt>
        </OfficerDirTrstKeyEmplGrp>
        <OfficerDirTrstKeyEmplGrp>
          <PersonNm referenceDocumentId="CompensationExplanation1" referenceDocumentName="CompensationExplanation">Caitlin Gase</PersonNm>
          <USAddress>
            <AddressLine1Txt>4530 McCorkle Ln</AddressLine1Txt>
            <CityNm>Sherrills Ford</CityNm>
            <StateAbbreviationCd>NC</StateAbbreviationCd>
            <ZIPCd>28673</ZIPCd>
          </USAddress>
          <TitleTxt>Treasurer</TitleTxt>
          <AverageHrsPerWkDevotedToPosRt>10.00</AverageHrsPerWkDevotedToPosRt>
          <CompensationAmt>0</CompensationAmt>
          <EmployeeBenefitProgramAmt>0</EmployeeBenefitProgramAmt>
          <ExpenseAccountOtherAllwncAmt>0</ExpenseAccountOtherAllwncAmt>
        </OfficerDirTrstKeyEmplGrp>
      </OfficerDirTrstKeyEmplInfoGrp>
      <SummaryOfDirectChrtblActyGrp>
        <Description1Txt>Fundraising activities</Description1Txt>
        <Expenses1Amt>5732</Expenses1Amt>
      </SummaryOfDirectChrtblActyGrp>
      <SumOfProgramRelatedInvstGrp />
      <MinimumInvestmentReturnGrp>
        <AverageMonthlyFMVOfSecAmt>1851</AverageMonthlyFMVOfSecAmt>
        <AverageMonthlyCashBalancesAmt>0</AverageMonthlyCashBalancesAmt>
        <FMVAllOtherNoncharitableAstAmt>0</FMVAllOtherNoncharitableAstAmt>
        <TotalFMVOfUnusedAssetsAmt>1851</TotalFMVOfUnusedAssetsAmt>
        <ReductionClaimedAmt referenceDocumentName="ReductionExplanationStatement">0</ReductionClaimedAmt>
        <AcquisitionIndebtednessAmt>93</AcquisitionIndebtednessAmt>
        <AdjustedTotalFMVOfUnusedAstAmt>1758</AdjustedTotalFMVOfUnusedAstAmt>
        <CashDeemedCharitableAmt referenceDocumentName="CashDeemedCharitableExplanationStatement">26</CashDeemedCharitableAmt>
        <NetVlNoncharitableAssetsAmt>1732</NetVlNoncharitableAssetsAmt>
        <MinimumInvestmentReturnAmt>87</MinimumInvestmentReturnAmt>
      </MinimumInvestmentReturnGrp>
      <DistributableAmountGrp>
        <MinimumInvestmentReturnAmt>87</MinimumInvestmentReturnAmt>
        <TaxBasedOnInvestmentIncomeAmt>0</TaxBasedOnInvestmentIncomeAmt>
        <IncomeTaxAmt>309</IncomeTaxAmt>
        <TotalTaxAmt>309</TotalTaxAmt>
        <DistributableBeforeAdjAmt>0</DistributableBeforeAdjAmt>
        <RecoveriesQualfiedDistriAmt>0</RecoveriesQualfiedDistriAmt>
        <DistributableBeforeDedAmt>0</DistributableBeforeDedAmt>
        <DeductionFromDistributableAmt>0</DeductionFromDistributableAmt>
        <DistributableAsAdjustedAmt>0</DistributableAsAdjustedAmt>
      </DistributableAmountGrp>
      <PFQualifyingDistributionsGrp>
        <ExpensesAndContributionsAmt referenceDocumentName="BorrowedFundsElection">0</ExpensesAndContributionsAmt>
        <ProgramRelatedInvstTotalAmt>0</ProgramRelatedInvstTotalAmt>
        <CharitableAssetsAcquisPaidAmt>0</CharitableAssetsAcquisPaidAmt>
        <SetAsideSuitabilityTestAmt>0</SetAsideSuitabilityTestAmt>
        <SetAsideCashDistriTestAmt referenceDocumentId="CashDistributionExplStmt1" referenceDocumentName="CashDistributionExplanationStatement">0</SetAsideCashDistriTestAmt>
        <QualifyingDistributionsAmt>0</QualifyingDistributionsAmt>
      </PFQualifyingDistributionsGrp>
      <UndistributedIncomeGrp>
        <DistributableAsAdjustedAmt>0</DistributableAsAdjustedAmt>
        <UndistributedIncomePYAmt>526</UndistributedIncomePYAmt>
        <TotalExcessDistributionCyovAmt>0</TotalExcessDistributionCyovAmt>
        <QualifyingDistributionsAmt>0</QualifyingDistributionsAmt>
        <AppliedToCurrentYearAmt>1250</AppliedToCurrentYearAmt>
        <ExcessDistriCyovAppCYCorpusAmt>0</ExcessDistriCyovAppCYCorpusAmt>
        <TotalCorpusAmt>0</TotalCorpusAmt>
        <PriorYearUndistributedIncmAmt>0</PriorYearUndistributedIncmAmt>
        <Taxable1Amt>0</Taxable1Amt>
        <Taxable2Amt>526</Taxable2Amt>
        <UndistributedIncomeCYAmt>-1250</UndistributedIncomeCYAmt>
        <ExcessDistriCyovToNextYrAmt>0</ExcessDistriCyovToNextYrAmt>
      </UndistributedIncomeGrp>
      <SupplementaryInformationGrp>
        <ApplicationSubmissionInfoGrp>
          <RecipientPersonNm>Meredith Haga Foundation</RecipientPersonNm>
          <RecipientUSAddress>
            <AddressLine1Txt>2970 Highway 11W</AddressLine1Txt>
            <CityNm>Blountville</CityNm>
            <StateAbbreviationCd>TN</StateAbbreviationCd>
            <ZIPCd>37617</ZIPCd>
          </RecipientUSAddress>
          <RecipientPhoneNum>4233402090</RecipientPhoneNum>
          <RecipientEmailAddressTxt>bblessing@meredithhagafoundation.org</RecipientEmailAddressTxt>
          <FormAndInfoAndMaterialsTxt>The Meredith Haga Foundation; apply for assistance utilities rent fuel hospital parking to help during their surgery to donate an organ.</FormAndInfoAndMaterialsTxt>
          <SubmissionDeadlinesTxt>12 31 2022</SubmissionDeadlinesTxt>
          <RestrictionsOnAwardsTxt>We do not pay for lost wages.</RestrictionsOnAwardsTxt>
        </ApplicationSubmissionInfoGrp>
        <TotalGrantOrContriPdDurYrAmt>0</TotalGrantOrContriPdDurYrAmt>
      </SupplementaryInformationGrp>
    </IRS990PF>
    <ExplnOfNonFilingWithAGStmt documentId="ExplOfNonFilingWithAGStmt1" softwareId="21013404" softwareVersionNum="V1.0" documentName="ExplanationOfNonFilingWithAGStatement">
      <ExplanationTxt>Was unaware that needed to submit to the AG of Tennessee. Are in the process of changing our status from private to public but IRS is in no hurry to make this happen</ExplanationTxt>
    </ExplnOfNonFilingWithAGStmt>
    <OtherDecreasesSchedule documentId="OtherDecreasesSch1" softwareId="21013404" softwareVersionNum="V1.0" documentName="OtherDecreasesSchedule">
      <OtherDecreasesDetail>
        <Desc>PayPal Facebook Bank and Credit Card Fees. Postage</Desc>
        <Amt>13938</Amt>
      </OtherDecreasesDetail>
    </OtherDecreasesSchedule>
  </ReturnData>
</Return>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a Byte-Order-Mark placed in the very first byte of the file.

A simple programmatic solution is to look for the first "<" character and then strip anything before that, before trying to parse the XML.

Considering the text is US ascii, another possible solution is to save the file in US-ascii encoding in some text editor.

You mention "json" , "xml" and "parsing" as tags as of this moment, but not the language you are working with, so it is hard to understand what you are trying to do, and in what language.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the possibility of a BOM suggested by @AlexanderPicoli, another possible explanation is that the content you have supplied to the parser isn't what you think it is.

Sorry if that sounds like a patronising suggestion, but it's a silly mistake we all make from time to time, and if you search StackOverflow for the error message, then it turns out to be a common explanation.